# Can you assign a variable to a static class pointer?

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, unit-of-work

I have a class:

```
class Test
{
    static function .... etc
}
```

Is there a way to make a variable equal a pointer to the static class:

```
$test = Test;
```

I think I require this to fulfil my attempt at a Unit of Work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple set to `$test` class name.

For example using the following code:

```
<?php

class Test
{
    static function myTest()
    {
        echo __METHOD__."<br />";
    }
}


class Test2
{
    static function myTest()
    {
        echo __METHOD__."<br />";
    }
}

$test = 'Test';

$test::myTest();

$test = 'Test2';

$test::myTest();
```

you will get result:

```
Test::myTest
Test2::myTest
```

as expected

Comment: I am PHP dev for 8+ years and I did not know this. PHP always surprises me.

Comment: Oh, what the hell... how would this work lmao... PHP is looser than lucy!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 and @BojanT - you can look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php There is example `$className = 'Foo'; $instance = new $className(); ` so the same works for static methods.